# Toggle radiobutton via knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have about 4 separate radiobuttons that I am creating in mvc as:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.rad1, "" ,htmlAttributes: new { 
data_bind = "checked: ischecked", id = "rad1" }) Radio 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.rad2, "" ,htmlAttributes: new { data_bind = "checked: ischecked", id = "rad2" }) Radio 2
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.rad3, "", htmlAttributes: new { data_bind = "checked: ischecked", id = "rad3" }) Radio 3
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.rad4, "", htmlAttributes: new { data_bind = "checked: ischecked", id = "rad4" }) Radio 4
        </label>
    </div>
```

Radio 3 & 4 depend on radio 1 & 2.

If someone selects radio 1, they by default radio 3 is selected and radio 4 is disabled for selection.
If someone selects radio 2, they can either select radio 3 or radio 4.

On the first time the default selection is radio 2 and 4.

I can do this by jquery but not sure how to handle this via knockout.

Any inputs please?

Comment: Where is your KO Model?

Comment: I just have setup that as:  this.ischecked= ko.observable();  I am not sure how to handle the toggle here

Comment: Please take a moment and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See answer below.  Did this solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to a few things.  You need a dedicated ischecked observable in your view model for each one of your radio buttons, and create a function for each of the relevant radio button click events in your view model, and then put your rules in those functions.  Also you'll need an observable on rad4 to enable/disable it.  Then for each of the data_bind attributes add the event binding to handle those click events.

You end result view model should look something like this:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.rad1IsChecked = ko.observable();
    self.rad2IsChecked = ko.observable();
    self.rad3IsChecked = ko.observable();
    self.rad4IsChecked = ko.observable();

    self.rad4IsEnabled = ko.observable();

    self.rad1OnClick = function() {
        //Put whatever rules in here that you need, like this...
        if (self.rad1IsChecked()) {
            self.rad3IsChecked(true);
            self.rad4IsEnabled(false);
        }

        return true; //Need this to propagate click event, so that button works as usual.
    }

    self.rad2OnClick = function() {
        //Put whatever rules in here that you need, like this...
        if (self.rad2IsChecked()) {
            self.rad3IsChecked(false);
            self.rad4IsEnabled(true);
        }

        return true; //Need this to propagate click event, so that button works as usual.
    }
}
```

And your HTML data_bind for each should look something like this:

```
data_bind = "checked: rad1IsChecked, event: {click: rad1OnClick}"
data_bind = "checked: rad2IsChecked, event: {click: rad2OnClick}"
data_bind = "checked: rad3IsChecked"
data_bind = "checked: rad4IsChecked, enable: rad4IsEnabled"
```

Also, you might have to put an @ in front of your data_bind, like "@data_bind".  That's how I've done it in the past, but I'm not sure if MVC requires it.

Comment: Yes Thanks. Did some modifications to suit my code.

Comment: Good, glad to hear it!